# Examples of extending the default TensorBoard graph plugin as a 3rd-party plugin?

Tags: open-source, tensorboard

I am working on extending the features of the default **graph plugin** in TensorBoard for my specific use case. However, I don't want to directly contribute to the TensorBoard repository. Instead, my plan is to create a 3rd-party plugin by making a copy of the default graphs plugin, adding my desired features, and making it installable for my users using Pip.

While implementing this approach, I have encountered two major difficulties:

1. **Conflicts with the original graphs plugin**: The most obvious conflicts I've discovered so far are duplicated plugin names and duplicated custom element names in the .ts files. I have resolved these conflicts by renaming them. However, I would like to know if there are any deeper conflicts that I should be aware of.
2. **Version incompatibility with core TensorBoard code**: The default graphs plugin relies on external code, such as the [dependency on the tensorboard/backend module](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/54129b306ec9520450a0afb65a05ebac8a065f7a/tensorboard/plugins/graph/graphs_plugin.py#L23-L24). Since TensorBoard is continuously evolving, there's a chance that future changes in the core code might render my plugin incompatible. How can I avoid this issue? Should I include a copy of all the core code as part of my plugin?

I would greatly appreciate any advice, examples, or experiences from anyone who has tackled similar challenges. If you have successfully created a 3rd-party plugin by extending the default graph plugin or have insights into handling conflicts and version compatibility, I would love to learn from you.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and discussions!